# Subdivision surface viewport problem - edges buried in mesh

Tags: 3d-view, subdivision-surface

I'm doing retopology with subdivision surface and shrinkwrap modifiers. In yesterday's project, the viewport behaved like this:

[image: correct]

Today it looks like this:

[image: wrong]

The problem is that the "control points" (actually just the pre-modifier mesh) gets buried inside the mesh and I can't see what I'm doing. In the other file the edges were curved with the subdivisions, making sure they were always visible.

The subdivision surface modifier settings are identical for the two files, so the issue must be elsewhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

[image]

The trick is the little triangle icon (Adjust edit cage to modifier result) on *the shrinkwrap modifier*

Again, *not* on the subdivision surface modifier but on the shrinkwrap.

Comment: That button will get enabled on both modifiers actually since enabling it to the second modifier in stack makes first adjust its result to the cage as well. However that's true that if you have such jagged edges of the lowpoly look up the modifiers, since edge made of 2 vertices dy definition can't be anything other than straight